# Errores referenciados a mscorlib en Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy aprendiendo de a poco a desarrollar Back-End y creando un sistema para un banco, al momento de compilar mi programa saltan muchos errores como estos

```
Error   CS0012  El tipo 'Attribute' está definido en un ensamblado al que no se hace referencia. Debe agregar una referencia al ensamblado 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.   1_nuevosocio.aspx   C:\Users\agusi\source\repos\ProyectoCEJUB\nuevosocio.aspx   1   Activo

Error   CS0012  El tipo 'Enum' está definido en un ensamblado al que no se hace referencia. Debe agregar una referencia al ensamblado 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    1_nuevosocio.aspx   C:\Users\agusi\source\repos\ProyectoCEJUB\nuevosocio.aspx   1   Activo

Error   CS0012  El tipo 'Object' está definido en un ensamblado al que no se hace referencia. Debe agregar una referencia al ensamblado 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.  1_nuevosocio.aspx   C:\Users\agusi\source\repos\ProyectoCEJUB\nuevosocio.aspx   1   Activo

Error   CS0234  El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices' (¿falta alguna referencia de ensamblado?)    1_nuevosocio.aspx   C:\Users\agusi\source\repos\ProyectoCEJUB\nuevosocio.aspx   1   Activo

Error   CS0518  El tipo predefinido 'System.Object' no está definido ni importado   3_default.aspx  C:\Users\agusi\source\repos\ProyectoCEJUB\default.aspx  1   Activo

Error   CS0518  El tipo predefinido 'System.String' no está definido ni importado   3_default.aspx  C:\Users\agusi\source\repos\ProyectoCEJUB\default.aspx  1   Activo

Error   CS0518  El tipo predefinido 'System.Void' no está definido ni importado 3_default.aspx  C:\Users\agusi\source\repos\ProyectoCEJUB\default.aspx  1   Activo
```

Traté de buscar soluciones en muchos lados y me dicen que tengo que agregar la referencia mscorlib pero cuando la quiero agregar no me deja ya que el sistema lo hace automaticamente.

Comment: Y si creas un proyecto nuevo, pasa lo mismo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.